# How to Create Bluemix Secure Gateway from rest api

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I am following [this doc](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/apidocs/25-secure-gateway?=undefined&language=node&env_id=ibm:yp:au-syd#this-operation-lists-all-existing-secure-gateway-c) for reference.
I am able to get information for secure gateway, which is already created. But when I am trying to create a new secure gateway from the REST API, it is asking for authentication. I have tried to provide the authentication information two ways:

- I have provided the oauth authorization header obtained from the `cf oauth-token`, but it gives me an unauthorized error.
- I have given basic authentication (username and password of the Bluemix account) information, but it gives me an unauthorized error.

Note: I am using postman for this operation

Postman details:

```
url: https://sgmanager.au-syd.bluemix.net/v1/sgconfig?org_id=girishxxxxxxx@gmail.com&space_id=Equxxxxx
```

[image]

It is also saying "Invalid org_id", but the `org_id` is valid.

Comment: Could you add details on the API call and the error?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: IMHO the org_id should be the guid. You can obtain it on the command line via `cf org yourOrgName --guid`.

Comment: @data_henrik Its worked. Thanks!

Comment: For space guid cf space yourSpaceName --guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a gateway via the SG API, your request will need the query parameters `ord_id` and `space_id` (the guids, not the friendly names).  The authorization header will be `Basic <your_base64_encoded_username:password>` or `Bearer <bluemix_token>`.  For example:

```
curl "https://sgmanager.au-syd.bluemix.net/v1/sgconfig?org_id=myOrgGuid&space_id=mySpaceGuid" -H "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" -d '{"desc":"My Gateway"}'
```

Comment: Worked For me
Thanks!